# What is the correct syntax when specifying the utxos to be used in c-lightning's `withdraw`?

Tags: json-rpc, utxo, core-lightning

I tried to withdraw from one utxo with the following command:

```
lightning-cli -k withdraw destination=bc1********** satoshi=******* feerate=normal utxos='["********":"0"]'
```

and I got the following output:

```
lightning-cli: Some parameters are malformed, cannot create a valid JSON-RPC request: { "jsonrpc" : "2.0", "method" : "withdraw", "id" : "lightning-cli-17786", "params" :{ "destination" : "bc*******", "satoshi" : ******, "feerate" : "normal", "utxos" : ["******":"0"]} }
```

Similar notation of square brackets inside of single quotes worked in `fundchannel`. What is the correct notation when it comes to specifying the utxos with `withdraw`?

P.S. I used `*` instead of the characters of the actual transaction in order to avoid doxxing myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry if this can be a little bit confusing, but the correct syntax is the following one:

```
clightning -k withdraw destination=** satoshi=** feerate=normal utxos='[{"********":"0"}]'
```

In particular, a transaction is an object, so the utxos is a list of transactions objects.